# Why is user environment variable Path invalid in windows cmd?

Tags: path, environment-variables

I often set java in system environment variable, which will make it accessible in windows cmd, but people won't always have admin access on their computer. When I set the Path environment variable under a specific account. I was not able to use java in windows cmd even if I log in as that account?

Why is it so? And how can I set append any thing to Path permanently without using admin access?

```
C:\Users\xxx>cygwin
'cygwin' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, I put cygwin folder under my C:\cygwin, which will make it admin access. After I change the user control to full, it is able to load the cygwin.

So namely, 
1. Put admin access program (like C:\Program Files) under your system variable 
2. Put local access program (lizhi C:\users\xxx) under your user account variable. 
Then it will work as expected.

Thanks